# Error when building Apache Cordova project in Visual Studio - Could not find module \node_modules\vs-tac\app.js (again!)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I fixed this or a very similar issue with building in debug (and I assume in a release version) my Visual Studio 2015 Community TACO Apache Cordova project (the one I'm working on or a blank new project from the template - which is what I've provided output from here, below, the blank one)  just about 24 hours ago, but now the problem has 'mysteriously' reappeared.

```
Error Cannot find module 'C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3TestZ\BlankCordovaApp3TestZ\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'
```

(the last part of the path does not exist, i.e. there is no \node_modules\ folder. There is a vs-tac folder here, of course,

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
```

,as mentioned in the BUILD output at the bottom. Some updated info: I see that the project which I was successfully debugging before I un/re-installed all my project plugins does have the node_modules folder with many sub-folders but not vs-tac.

I had everything working: debug on Ripple, Android AVDs, my Android device.  Two days ago I cleared the Cordova cache (for a stupid reason) and started getting the error.

After hours of troubleshooting, I got it working again, I thought by running (my last try):

```
npm install -g npm
```

## Before that I had attempted fixing by -->

- Clearing the cache again
- Renaming the folder: C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon (So that VS recereates it)
- Renaming the folder C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\vs-npm  (So that VS recereates it)
- Tried to re-install vs-tac (no quotes on the path, didnt work, but I got the issue resolved anyway - today I used the quotes)
- Verified the npmrc file had the fix: i.e. its content was --> prefix=C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm

After again being able to debug, I came to a point today where i decided to uninstall my project's jquery module (2.2.3), and it looked like i need to uninstall jquery.mobile (1.4.5) and Bootstrap (3.3.7) also to do so, since I thought I might have a too high version of jquery causing an issue with my project's code. I re-installed the same except jquery at 2.1.0.

After the module uninstall/reinstall just mentioned the vs-tac issue came back! Also, for the first time, an NPM dependency not installed issue in the dependency tree! After a little messing around, I opened a new Apache Cordova project from the template... the dependency issue is gone but not the vs-tac build issue.

I have tried all of the above fix atttemps again today and cannot resolve it this time, so far...

## Here is the output from some of those attempts at fixing my issue today (from an Admin Node.js command prompt) -->

```
C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g npm
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm -> C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\npx -> C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js
+ npm@5.3.0
updated 1 package in 64.141s //This update seems to happen every time I run this command, which is odd for something global

C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\Packages\vs-tac"
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-tac-cli -> C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\vs-tac-cli.cmd
+ vs-tac@1.0.42
updated 1 package in 4.406s
```

#### ENVIRONMENT INFORMATION -->

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.02046
Installed Version: Community
Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova   Update 10
Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA328
JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Project System   2.0

In VS Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools I have:
C:\Program Files\nodejs (at the top, then)
.\node_modules\.bin
$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External
$(PATH)
$(VSINSTALLDIR)\Web\External\git
(all above are checked - not changed recently)  

I don't think what is in VS Tools > Options > Tools for Apache Cordova > Environment Variable Overrides is relevant in this case and did not include.

Cordova CLI --> 6.1.1 (per the test project's config.xml)   

// From VS Package Manager Conole -->
Path 
----                          
C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3TestZ\BlankCordovaApp3TestZ // this is my new template test project

PM> node -v
v6.9.1
PM> npm list cordova
BlankCordovaApp3TestZ@1.0.0 C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3TestZ\BlankCordovaApp3TestZ
`-- (empty)

PM> npm list -g cordova
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- cordova@7.0.1 

PM> cordova platform version android
Installed platforms:

Available platforms: 
  android ~6.2.2
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  browser ~4.1.0
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~5.0.0
```

#### Full BUILD Output (for DEBUG ANDROID DEVICE) -->

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp3TestZ, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.42
1>  ------ Package not currently installed globally.
1>  ------ Installing globally from source package. This could take a few minutes...
1>  Each package is licensed to you by its owner. Microsoft is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.
1>  ENOENT, no such file or directory ''
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : module.js:338
1>  module.js:338
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  throw err;
1>      throw err;
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  ^
1>            ^
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD401: Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3TestZ\BlankCordovaApp3TestZ\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.
1>  Error Cannot find module 'C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3TestZ\BlankCordovaApp3TestZ\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
1>      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
1>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
1>      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at startup (node.js:129:16)
1>      at startup (node.js:129:16)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  at node.js:814:3
1>      at node.js:814:3
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

New stuff I'm trying today -->

```
npm config set prefix %APPDATA%\npm
npm config set cache %APPDATA%\npm-cache
```

(because I also copied vs-tac into my roaming folder at some point)...this had no effect on build.

Also, realized my config.xml had CLI set to 6.1.1, so i changed this to match the globally installed version, 7.0.1 - no effect on build.

Any assistance much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: exact same problem and none of the solutions on the web helped me out. Hope someone figures this out

Comment: I upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 Community and have not seen this problem.